# Note page showing the next frame

Tags: beamer, programming, presentations

I would like to customise the note pages in Beamer to show:

1. the current frame that they refer to with its number,
2. the next frame of the presentation with its number,
3. the section and subsection,
4. the notes themselves.

The reason for this is to make a useful *presenter view* for presentations on a secondary screen (using [SplitShow](http://code.google.com/p/splitshow/) on a Mac). I have noticed a considerable demand for the same so I am hoping to release the solution as a package or perhaps contact the Beamer maintainer and offer it for incorporation.

The the only problem yet is that due to my inexperience in programming for LaTeX, I can not figure out how to insert the content of next frame. The current frame (or slide) is inserted as follows (beamerbasenotes.sty):

```
\newcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{#1\paperwidth}{#1\paperheight}
    \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{#1}}%
      \color[gray]{1}
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \color{black}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\beamer@origlmargin}{\footheight}}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}
    \end{pgflowlevelscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  }}
```

I do not understand what does `\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy` represent.

**Could you please provide me with a command definition that would produce the same with the next frame instead of the current one?**

The intended result:

[image: The intended result.]

Comment: Regarding the display of the next frame, there is [a feature request for this in the `beamer` repository](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/5/more-slide-thumbnails-in-notes). Somebody even provided an updated version of `beamerbasenotes.sty` which introduces the `\insertnextslideintonotes` macro. However, this doesn't work too well, at least with my `beamer` version 3.12. (If I use the new file in a MWE, the last slide simply vanishes...)

Comment: In light of diabonas' comment, I'm wary of trying a *direct* solution to this!  However, it strikes me that there may be a dirty hack that would fix this.  That would be to fix it so that a notes page consisted of the previous frame, the frame before that, and the notes for that prior frame.  Then use a page-reordering tool, such as `pdftk`, to reorder the pages.  If all pages have notes (which would seem reasonable from your use-case) then the reordering is obvious.  Would that be an acceptable half-way solution?

Comment: @diabonas I am sorry for failing to answer sooner, thank you for bringing my attention to it. I experience the same problem as you when using the code provided – the last frame goes missing.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I was primarily interested in how it can be done using LaTeX and while your solution is smart and great for real application, I am still eager to know why it is technically difficult to display the next frame. Could you please explain it to me? For now, I am going to use the method that you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: (Didn't see your reply, sorry) The inclusion of the frame in a note is done by saving a copy of the box that it produces.  So to use the frame in advance, you are going to have to seriously mess with the order in which boxes are produced.  The notes and frames stuff already does a bit of this juggling, but it is Deep Magic and I, for one, would leave it to the experts (this is what I mean by "in light of diabonas' comment".  Since there is a feature request, that means that the experts are aware of it and maybe trying to do it.  I doubt I could do any better so I wouldn't.) ctd

Comment: (ctd) The difficulty is, presumably, in keeping all the boxes in the air at the same time, and there might be things that would need very careful handling (should definitions in the notes page affect the *next* frame?).  *Functionally*, though, I think that the result would be the same as my suggestion using something like `pdftk`: render all the necessary pages and then juggle them into the right order.  I agree, though, that a purely LaTeX method would be nice for this as I always feel like I'm Messing With Things Man Was Not Meant To Wot Of when using `pdftk`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you for the explanation, Andrew. I myself failed to reply earlier due to work—for that I apologise. Like you wrote, I shall leave it to the experts and use alternative solutions just as the one you suggested in the meantime (the other being _PDF to Keynote_ and using Keynote's presenter view). As to this question, I think that an answer mentioning the feature request and at least the two alternatives would be appropriate to accept. If you provide one, I shall do so.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: The op wants that you answer ;-)

Comment: @diabonas, the updated version of `beamerbasenotes.sty` is not longer available. Has anyone saved this file? The [feature request in the beamer repository](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/5/more-slide-thumbnails-in-notes) is still open, apparently... Looks like the proposed solution there worked (if replacing the last frame with a blank one) but it's not available any more.

Comment: @anderfo Unfortunately I don't have a copy of this file, and it doesn't seem to be available elsewhere on the Internet either :-( You could try contacting the author of the patched version, Marco Lombardi: [http://www.marcolombardi.org/home/contacts](http://www.marcolombardi.org/home/contacts)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a sneaky way to accomplish this without using any external tools.  It's a "proof of concept" more than a complete solution, but I think it would be usable if a little rough around the edges.

It uses an enhanced `pgfpages`.  The enhancement means that when `pgfpages` comes to lay out its logical pages on a physical page, it can do so on more than one physical page.  So what we do is we gather together the notes page and the next frame page then typeset them as usual: notes followed by frame (since the frame is the *next* one), but with a little extra: we also put the frame page in the top corner of the notes page.

Modulo a little trickery to ensure that we start and end at the right points, and that we actually don't want to use the full frame but only its contents (ie not the background), this isn't overly complicated.  It does mean we get two extra slides: one at the start and one at the end, but even that could be dealt with without too much extra hassle.

The enhanced `pgfpages` is called `pgfmorepages.sty` ([CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages) and [github](https://github.com/loopspace/pgfmorepages)).  With that, the following code works-for-me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33051/86}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{note page}{lookahead}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \insertvrule{.25\paperheight}{white!90!black}
    \vskip-.25\paperheight
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox{
      \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\hskip0.25\paperwidth\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
      \vskip-0.25\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
        \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
          {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
          \pgftext[base,left]{\footnotesize\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
        \end{pgflowlevelscope}
      \end{pgfpicture}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .25\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{notes page with look ahead}%
{%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
  \def\pgfpageoptioninitialshipout{2}
}%
{%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=3,%
    physical pages=2,%
    physical height=\the\paperheight,%
    physical width=\the\paperwidth,%
    current logical shipout=2,%
    last logical shipout=2,%
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{1}{%
    skip code={\ifnum\the\pgfactualpage=1\relax\pgfpagesshipfalse\fi}
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}%
  {
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}%
  {
    resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.875\pgfphysicalheight},%
    border code={\color[gray]{0.8}\pgfusepath{stroke}},%
    skip code={%
      \ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@2\endcsname\else
      \setbox\csname pgfpages@box@3\endcsname=\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy\fi
      }
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{2}{%
    skip code={\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@2\endcsname\pgfpagesshipfalse\fi}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}%
  {
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[lookahead]
\pgfpagesuselayout{notes page with look ahead}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The first frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The second frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The third frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The fourth frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course, one ought to hide that horrible stuff in another `.sty` file.  Also, I've no doubt that there are better layouts - I just hacked the current one that puts the image of the previous slide in the top corner.

This produces the following.

[image: Beamer with notes and following frame]

---

*Edit 2014-09-20*

In response to anderfo's comment (which I never got round to looking at) and a similar question by email, I proffer the following.  First, I should say that as it has been a long time since I looked at this code, I find I no longer fully understand it!  However, by my usual 'hack and see' approach, I've managed to get something that (I think!) simulates the "show notes on second screen=left" layout.  It also corrects the offset that Jim points out (again by "magic numbers", not by understanding what's going on).

(One minor annoyance is that on the last slide, a "next slide" still appears.  I've not figured out how to get rid of that.)

[image: Beamer with notes on second slide]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33051/86}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{note page}{lookahead}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \insertvrule{.25\paperheight}{white!90!black}
    \vskip-.25\paperheight
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox{
      \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\hskip0.25\paperwidth\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
      \vskip-0.25\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
        \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
          {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
          \pgftext[base,left]{\footnotesize\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
        \end{pgflowlevelscope}
      \end{pgfpicture}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .25\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}


\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{notes page with look ahead}%
{%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
  \def\pgfpageoptioninitialshipout{2}
}%
{%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=3,%
    physical pages=2,%
    physical height=\the\paperheight,%
    physical width=\the\paperwidth,%
    current logical shipout=2,%
    last logical shipout=2,%
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{1}{%
    skip code={\ifnum\the\pgfactualpage=1\relax\pgfpagesshipfalse\fi}
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}%
  {
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}%
  {
    resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.875\pgfphysicalheight},%
    border code={\color[gray]{0.8}\pgfusepath{stroke}},%
    skip code={%
      \ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@2\endcsname\else
      \setbox\csname pgfpages@box@3\endcsname=%
\hbox to \pgfphysicalwidth{%
\hskip-.6in% No idea why this is the right value
\vbox to \pgfphysicalheight{%
\vskip-1in%
\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}\fi
      }%
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{2}{%
    skip code={\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@2\endcsname\pgfpagesshipfalse\fi}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}%
  {
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{notes page on second screen left with look ahead}%
{%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
  \def\pgfpageoptioninitialshipout{2}
}%
{%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=3,%
    physical pages=1,%
    physical height=\the\paperheight,%
    physical width=2\paperwidth,%
    current logical shipout=1,%
    last logical shipout=2,%
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{1}{%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}%
  {
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}%
  {
    resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.4375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.875\pgfphysicalheight},%
    border code={\color[gray]{0.8}\pgfusepath{stroke}},%
    skip code={%
      \ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@2\endcsname\else
      \setbox\csname pgfpages@box@3\endcsname=%
\hbox to \pgfphysicalwidth{%
\hskip-.6in% No idea why this is the right value
\vbox to \pgfphysicalheight{%
\vskip-1in%
\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}\fi
      }%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}%
  {
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[lookahead]
\pgfpagesuselayout{notes page on second screen left with look ahead}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{notes page with look ahead}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The first frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The second frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The third frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The fourth frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An item
\note[item]{with a note}
\item Another item
\note[item]{with another note}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill
Something near the bottom
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, this is a nice solution, thank you! (I was on a holiday so excuse my late reaction, please.)

Comment: Given that the question was over half a year ago, I think you're excused!  Incidentally, the latest version of the code can get rid of the extra pages.  If you ever use this "for real", let me know how you get on.

Comment: This solution is great (and works), but is there any way to make it work with the `show notes on second screen=left` option?

Comment: @anderfo I've no idea!  I'll have a look when I get a minute.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a way to line up the next page preview any better?  It needs to be shifted up and to left some.  I've tried playing around and changing some of the numbers that are already there, but none of them seem to do the trick.  And I'm not quite savvy enough to figure out where in that code does the second slide actually get inserted.

Comment: BTW @AndrewStacey, thanks for this.  I'm a mathematics PhD student.  I used this template for my general exam talk and even with the slightly wonky alignment of the preview slide it worked great!  I have three conference talks coming up in the next two weeks and I'll be using this for all of them.

Comment: @Jim I found the "magic numbers", more or less.

Comment: @anderfo Don't know if it's still useful, but I hacked something together.

Comment: Is it not possible to define a new command `\insertslideintonoteslookahead{0.25}`? Because now the look a head slide is in the same function.

Comment: @anderfo can you provide a more preceise link? There ist quite a bunch of stuff on that link in your coment called "loop Space"...

Comment: @novski did you mean that comment for me? anderfo doesn't link to anything in his comment as far as I can see.

Comment: ah no i just saw that its not a link but a username with link "- loop Space". Did you make that work with "show notes on secod screen" somehow? I can't find out how to get that done...

Comment: @novski I wrote the answer that these comments are attached to (as evidenced by my username being at the bottom of the post).  However, it was over 2 years ago so if you have a question about it then it is probably worth asking a fresh question giving details about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A nice workaround is available at https://www.eigenheimstrasse.de/~ben/beamernotepage/.

Basically a makefile is used to first compile the normal presentation without notes and then use the frames from this presentation as images in the version with notes. In addition some extra elements are added to the note page, like an overview of the sections.

Sample of the output:

[image]