# Beamer second screen with next slide

Tags: beamer, presentations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Note page showing the next frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame)

I just presented some of my work with a presentation typeset with LaTeX+Beamer, using the double screen magic of

```
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
```

which helped me a lot with those pesky transition phrases and words that I forget when nervous.

I also used [impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) in order to put some decent transitions and make all those keynote and powerpoint users a bit jealous (useless, everyone was already on beamer). The result was very satisfying and the presentation went particularly well.

There was something, however, that I would have loved. In the second screen (the notes pages), I had a smaller version of the current slide showing in the first screen. It would have been just perfect if I had another smaller version of the **next** slide. I have seen this in keynote and I think it would help a lot the presenter. 
Is it possible to have a smaller rendered version of the next slide?
It seems feasible since one already has the current slide... but then again, I have my doubts since the next slide has not been typeset yet.

Comment: This seems more like the sort of thing that impressive could do, rather than something to do from within beamer.

Comment: To follow up on the linked duplicate, I recently wanted more advanced layouts than currently possible with `pgfpages` so hacked it a little to the point where I might be able to provide an answer to this.  But I need a clear space to think through the idea a bit more carefully to test it.

Comment: @Seamus: Two reasons to do it with beamer/pgf: 1) impressive seems stuck and last stable version is from some time ago. 2) beamer already does this for the current slide

Comment: @AndrewStacey I had not find that question before... sure, this is a duplicate

Comment: You probably don't get notifications of the duplicate, so I'm just mentioning that I've posted an answer to the original question.