# Which PDF viewers for Linux support Beamer's second screen options?

Tags: beamer, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Note page showing the next frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame)
>   [Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux)

I have tried evince and Adobe Reader on Linux, but neither seems capable of displaying Beamer's two-screen slides in full-screen. They just display double-wide slides with all of the content on one of the screens.

Comment: Relaved question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux (not exactly a duplicate, but it is possible that answers to this question help the other and conversely)

Comment: Adobe reader is capable of such things, however, it is the display driver that you need to setup to do these kind of things (how should Reader otherwise know that you have two separate screens and not one?). This is better asked on linux sites, it is not specifically related to TeX or beamer. Good question though! :)

Comment: what operating system you're working?

Comment: I am trying this on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: maybe this helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame

Comment: In T. Vernon's suggested [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux), I found this [paper](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/dohmen/). It looks promising. I'll try this out to see if it helps.