# Beamer - Title page is perturbed when adding notes

Tags: beamer, titles, nodes, notes

I'm working on a Beamer presentation in which I want my notes to be along with a small preview of the current slide only (bigger than the default). I worked on the following MWE, which seems to work ok, except for the fact that I changed my title page to be tikzpicture nodes...

Now the title slide looks ok if I do not add nodes, but becomes completely unstructured when I add the notes...

I guess there is something simple to be changed in the relative/absolute positions of the nodes, but I have tried many things and I cannot reproduce the look of the slide without notes when I add the notes...

This the MWE:

```
\listfiles

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% For normal presentations WITHOUT NOTES
%\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{etex}
%\reserveinserts{28}
%\setbeameroption{hide notes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% For presentations WITH NOTES
%\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{etex}
%\reserveinserts{28}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% For handouts with lots of extra notes
\documentclass[handout, ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm] % could also use letterpaper
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pink}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
        \node [rectangle, fill=gray, anchor=north east, minimum width=.86\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north east){};
        \node at ($(box.west)+(.1,0)$) [anchor=east]{\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image}};


        \node[anchor=center, align=left, font=\color{white}\usebeamerfont{title}] (title) at ($(box)+(0,.25)$)
        {\inserttitle};

            \ifx\insertauthor\@empty
        \else
        \node [anchor=west, font=\color{white}\usebeamerfont{author}] (author) at ($(title.south west)-(0,.5)$) {
            {\insertauthor}
            };
            \fi

            \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty
        \else
        \node [anchor=center] (institute) at ($(box.south)-(0,1.5)$) {%
            {\insertinstitute}
            };
            \fi

            \ifx\insertdate\@empty
        \else
        \node [anchor=west, font=\color{blue}\usebeamerfont{date}] (date) at ($(institute.south west)-(-.2,2)$) {%
            {\insertdate}
            };
            \fi



        \node [anchor=west] (email) at ($(date.south west)-(2.52,1)$) {%
        \color{blue}
            {\scriptsize \email}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\newlength{\parskipbackup}
\setlength{\parskipbackup}{\parskip}
\newlength{\parindentbackup}
\setlength{\parindentbackup}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\baselinestretchbackup}{\baselinestretch}

\usetemplatenote{

  \insertslideintonotes{0.3}%

  \rmfamily \scriptsize%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1em} \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%

  \insertnote%

  \setlength{\parskip}{\parskipbackup}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\parindentbackup}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\baselinestretchbackup}%
}



\title[short title]{full title}
\author{John Smith}
\date[\today]{\today}
\newcommand{\email}{\textit{john@smith.com}}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\note{this is a note}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is the first slide
\note{this is another note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces [image: this absolutely beautiful title slide]

But if you comment the first block and uncomment the second to add the notes in an A4 handout format, you will get [image: this completely ugly title page]...

Can anyone help me with this??

A SUPER BONUS would be if anyone would be able to place a smaller preview of the following slide alongside the preview of the current slide!!

**EDIT:**

I'm including below the \listfiles output (check the slight changes in the MWE):

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2012/10/15 development version 3.24 A class for typesetting pres
entations (rcs-revision 24853e6b98cf)
beamerbasercs.sty    2012/11/13 (rcs-revision cb16a617839f)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2012/04/15 (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2010/04/27 (rcs-revision 982469101dd6)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2012/09/19  (rcs-revision 733629cd0c6c)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2012/02/24  (rcs-revision 2ff5461be705)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 6afbc49b1109)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 0056eef6f17f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2012/10/02  (rcs-revision 5ed0f4010e8a)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2012/11/13  (rcs-revision ddfba79dac19)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2012/04/03  (rcs-revision 42a0f21a412d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/10/02  (rcs-revision 5ed0f4010e8a)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
pgfpages.sty    2004/11/05 ver 0.01
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 ot1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
       b.out
       b.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
example-image.png    Graphic file (type png)
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

**NEW EDIT!!**
As in [this other related question I posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193277/printing-a-handout-of-a-beamer-presentation-the-resulting-pdf-is-shrinked), if I place the line "\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}" after the line "\setbeameroption{show notes}" the title slide remains perfectly unperturbed as it should be!! However, the slide preview and notes that appear at the bottom belong to the NEXT SLIDE, instead of to the CURRENT SLIDE!! What is going on with that?

Let see if anyone could help me make this work also for the 2nd commented block on the MWE to have the notes on the left. Thanks!!

Comment: When I compile your MWE I get something different.  The top half of the handout version has the slide just as it appears with the beamer version.  The bottom half of the handout version has a mini version of the slide (without the background) and your notes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, what I would like is the main slide in the handout version exactly as it looks in the presentation version, and the small one below with the stuff inside correctly placed as well, with the notes below.... Did you change anything in the code?? cause I get it like in the 2nd image every time...

Comment: and a simple way to include the next slide along the current one in the notes... something not as messy as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame if possible...

Comment: Can anybody reproduce the error? I am on Ubuntu 14.04, using texlive 2013 and texmaker 4.1-1, and compile it with LuaLaTeX + View PDF

Comment: It is worth noting that if I remove "\insertslideintonotes{0.3}" the main title slide looks correct in handout format, but I do not want to remove "\insertslideintonotes{0.3}"... Can anybody help with this??

Comment: I'm still stuck with this, I'd really appreciate if anybody could help... Thanks!!!

Comment: You might want to remove any temporary files and recompile to see if the unwanted behavior persists.  As for your second request of putting the next slide in the note page...this would be a nice feature but seems pretty hard to implement because TeX goes through the file in one pass, shipping out pages as it goes.  To put a future slide on a page you'd have to save it from a prior run and insert it.  Could work, but not a simple task.

Comment: yeah I already gave up on the next slide feature... but I always get the problem with the title page, I tried removing temporary files and recompile, I tried changing nodes positioning, and I have the latest stable versions of Ubuntu (14.04), texlive (2013) and TexMaker (4.1-1)... the problem persists...

Comment: Put `\listfiles` in your preamble and add to your question the contents of the log file between `*File List*` and `*****`.

Comment: I've just edited the question to include the output of \listfiles

Comment: Looks like your version of beamer is older than mine.  I have 3.26 and you have 3.24.  So I would start by upgrading your beamer installation.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to upgrade Beamer under Ubuntu?? I found that the problem only happens when I do the title page using tikz nodes... would there be a way to obtain the exact same result without using nodes? Are nodes the best solution?

Comment: please check the new edit, with a simple change I managed to have the title slide unperturbed, but the notes and slide preview that appear belong to the next slide instead of to the current one

Comment: I can't reproduce with TeX Live 2013 or 2012. But both of those have version 2.26. So there is something wrong if you have 2.24. Maybe a problem with your distro's packaging. The easiest way to use TeX Live is to install from upstream and eradicate your distro's packages altogether. There are detailed instructions for doing this on Debian-based systems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be due to an out-of-date distribution